# How can I protect mysql password in a phoneGap app?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, html, cordova

I am creating a phoneGap app and want to connect to mysql database (as outlined in this article: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/mysql-nodejs-intro/), but I can't figure out a way to protect my password. Is there a way to protect your password in a phoneGap app? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want to connect from a phonegap App directly to a database... where? On some server? Why not just put a proper web app in front of it, like a node.js app?

Comment: Don't put your DB credentials in your app.  Your app should call your web API, which should handle accessing the DB and returning the data.

Answer (score 0):

The only way, which I know, to crypt an cordova app is this plugin:

https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file

But it is a bad idea and unsecure to have a call direct from your app to your MySQL. Write a small api which is between your app and the database, use https and check the certificate in your app.